# Finding an circle inside distribution of elemets

Tags: geometry

I've got a set of points in a 2 dimensional carthesian coordinate system. The points cover a coherent area and are arranged in a grid which is somehow triangular and have a somehow similar distance. "somehow" means, that the point distribution is derived from a perfect triangular grid by distorting it to some degree. So the angles and distances formed by and defined by the points will vary up to a certain degree, which cannot be predicted exactly. (of course it could be predicted, because the algorithm for the distortion is available, but this can change easily). We can further assume, the distribution has a rotational symmetry.

Now I want to find a circle with a maximum diameter which does not reach out of the cloud of points. I.e. a kind of inscribed circle. 
[image]

What might be a good aproach to calculating such a circle?

Updates for clarification:

- The circle shall contain only areas, where points "are". If you draw it somewhat bigger than in the example, there will be some "white" areas inside. This means, the circle is no longer completely "inside" the dotted area.
- The area may seem to be nearly triangular, but its sides may be bent much stronger than in the example.
- Given the rotational symmetry, finding the center of the circle is no problem, but finding the diameter is.
- Probably one needs to define first, what the "dotted area" in fact is.

Comment: Ok, the red thing in the picture actually isn't a circle, but you know what I mean.

Comment: no, we don't actually know what you mean. You say "does not reach out of the cloud of points"; however, you don't mathematically define that. Write down the mathematical inequalities that define your problem, and you'll be a lot closer to your solution. Then update your question.

Comment: If the distortion has rotational symmetry, there's a simple way to find the center of the circle: Identify the extreme points (the tips of the triangle, which are also the vertices of the convex closure), and plot the center point of the triangle they form.

Comment: if you're always going to have a roughly triangular area, would the [circle inscribed in a triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Incircle) work ?

Comment: Actually there's an even easier way to find the (approximate) center: Average the x coordinate of all points to get the center's x coordinate, and similarly for y.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza: The circle outline will be bent differently. If it is curved more strongly the triangle derived from the outer most points cannot be used.

Comment: @Ariser I see, good point!

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I don't define it mathematically, for a simple reason: I can't. I don't know, how to describe the problem with inequalities.

Comment: @Ariser: in that case, this is *by no means* a programming, but a math question. Before you solve the question of what exactly you want, we can't help you solve the question how to get that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller good point. What next? move it to math?